# what dose the sentence means in given text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

sentence: "While you won’t be repurposing it to be the next biggest blockbuster, you can still repurpose it for great revenue"

"What can you learn from this? That repurposing content is possible and is a great idea! It helps you get the most out of your content without making you spend days and weeks on new content. While you won’t be repurposing it to be the next biggest blockbuster, you can still repurpose it for great revenue. Ways to repurpose your content could be to use chapters from e-books as blogs, turning blogs into infographics, and making videos of your existing content. Make sure to take a page from Disney, however, and make your repurposed content unique!"

i think It means that: even if you cannot produce a great one, you can produce a good and acceptable one.

Answer (score 1):

"Repurposing" is an over-used bit of cant that means using something for a different purpose. For example, one could repurpose a coin as a screwdriver, or a toothpick as a glue applicator. The intent of the paragraph is that something may be reworked and used for a different purpose, rather than discarding it.